# Ctrl+Shift+Left or Right doesn't select words in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, text-editor

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 laptop. I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and then to 20.04. While working in 16.04 pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> used to select the word to the left of cursor. However, on upgrading to 18.04 and 20.04, this shortcut no longer selects words. In fact it does nothing.

On another note, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> moves the cursor to the left.

I have already tried to fix it using Tweaks, which suggested <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> might be used for *Switching to another layout*.

Comment: Difficult to understand. That surely won't work in vim, for example. It probably depends on the context what keyboard presses do. So you may want to describe a specific case where you expect this to work, but where it does not. Then others will be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do you happen to have *Locate Pointer* enabled in Settings -> *Universal Access*?

Comment: It used to work on text editors like, IntelliJ, Sublime, VisualStudio, even in chrome, where we draft a mail. But not now. @vanadium

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Locale Pointer is disabled under Universal Access

Comment: @abcd So you use `Ctrl`+`Shift` to switch to another layout? If so, can you try disabling this and use the default `Super`+`Space` shortcut for the layout switching and then check if `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Left` works? Also check if instead of `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Left` you can select the text using `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Left`, i.e. press `Shift` first, then `Ctrl`.